# Why are cockpit voice recorders limited to 2 hours recording?

Tags: cockpit-voice-recorder

With today's technology in memory storage, where simple voice recorders can record virtually endless durations, why are CVRs limited to only 2 hours. Is it the eternal "cost vs benefit" reason?

Wouldn't more recording provide greater insight to investigators in case of any disaster?

Comment: Conversation and cockpit noises prior to two hours before an accident are deemed not useful to help explain the accident, but they can contain privacy elements? Technical parameters recording is longer.

Comment: Lets see. 44.1 kHz * 2 B/channel * 5 channels * 2 h ~ 3 GiB. This is not compressed, but I think it indeed isn't, because compression would be another thing that might fail and it would render much more of the recording unreadable if there was minor damage to the chip. They may not be using as good quality, but on the other hand they may actually duplicate the recording. Add the age of the units, as it took some time to develop, certify and deploy them and the desire to use lower density chips that are more robust and it no longer sounds too easy to keep 2 hours.

Comment: Also, the “quick access recorder” usually keeps a lot more. But it does not have any of the reliability and durability requirements; it is intended for internal reviews after flight and possibly investigating incidents (= when something went wrong, but no serious injury or significant damage occurred).

Comment: Planes that fly today weren't built today, they were built yesterday, which means that today's technology didn't exist when they were built. By the way: did you try blowing up your simple voice recorder, then dropping it 30000 feet, then submerging it in aggressive salt water for 6 months, then plug it in and play it back? Did it work?

Comment: @JörgWMittag So you are trying to tell me that the current technology is not advanced enough to accommodate more than 2hours of great quality recording in the bullet proof CVRs?

Comment: @mins I'm just trying to understand this 2 hour rule, do you have some more on that. Common sense implies the more data the better, atleast for the entire duration of the flight.

Comment: A lot of pilots have privacy concerns with the CVRs already, I am sure ultimately the two hour limit is a balance point between investigation and privacy. This is the same reason the crew can clear the CVR after a flight. I work with a guy that listened to a full CVR after an accident that included the previous flight, on that previous flight the pilots were bashing their families hardcore and talking about sleeping around, not the kind of thing you want out in world after you die.

Comment: @Firee:  What do you imagine could have happened more than 2 hours ago that leads to an incident.   In virtually all cases, the time between "everything is normal" to "Sound of Impact" is less than 10 minutes.  Even flight Quantas 32 (one of the longest emergencies in history) was only 1:45 from engine failure to landing.   One rare exception is Payne Stewart's crash (roughly 3:30 from depressurization to crash).

Comment: @OSUZorba already explained the balance between privacy and investigation needs. Pilots (like everybody should) have a right to discuss in privacy. When you are at work (and they are) not everything you say is for work purpose, you need to relax, that's part of the well being required to work safely. If everything were recorded, everybody would be stressed, that's not what you want as a passenger. Regarding the state of technology, I agree with you that we could today record ten 6 kHz channels, for 20 hours *if we needed it*, only slow static memory is needed, not fast DDR.

Comment: @abelenky I can imagine these: [MH370](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malaysia_Airlines_Flight_370), [2014 TBM-900 crash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_SOCATA_TBM_crash), and [Helios 522](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helios_Airways_Flight_522) off the top of my head. Also, [QF32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qantas_Flight_32), though it didn't crash and the pilots could be interviewed. Sometimes things which happened much earlier in flight can end up causing problems later (Space Shuttle Columbia is an extreme example of this.)

Comment: I specifically cited QF32 as being under 2 hours from incident to landing.  We still don't have the location of the boxes from MH370, so 2 hours or 1,000 hours of recording time doesn't matter.  The other two are pressurization / hypoxia incidents which are well understood and additional recording time would not shed any new light.   I think you proved my point.  Thank you.

Comment: @abelenky Ah, so you did. Somehow I missed that sentence. However, I'm not sure when the CVR stopped on that flight, since they weren't able to shut down the #1 engine until 3 hours after landing. If the CVR didn't stop until the #1 engine was shut down (or after,) they'd have erased the entire relevant portion of the incident, other than the fight to shut down #1. With MH370, we don't have it yet, but hopefully we eventually will. However, we'll almost certainly not have the most important part of the flight recorded, due to the 2 hour limit.

Comment: Respecting pilot's privacy, the CVR recording can be deleted by the pilot at the end of the flight. In case there is an accident, I personally feel, safety would precede privacy. More information would indeed assist the investigators. Plus I'm sure, laws can be made to safeguard pilot's private conversations.

Comment: @reirab Exactly. Having more data, would always give a better insight.I'm yet to be convinced cost and technology are big hindrance to adopting this initiative. Pilot privacy is one valid point, but since pilots have the option of erasing the recording after landing, solves the issue of longer recordings. Ideally, the recording length should be from the moment pilots start operating in the cockpit.

Comment: @vasin1987 Why am i not able to see your comment? Instead I see a big white space.

Comment: @Firee must be some formatting issue. I can see my comment well in SE android app but big white space on iOS safari. I put a lot of dollar sign there. Basically it comes down to cost vs benefit arguement again.

Comment: @Firee you probably exceeded the 2-hour limit to read the comment, and it was erased.

Comment: @vasin1987 I cannot see your comment either. Dollar signs are a code-element of javascript, so it's possible that the server is interpreting it as script code to be executed. If so, you may have inadvertently discovered an injection vulnerability (hacking). Hopefully the admins will look at this soon.

Comment: @DrZ214 Hogwash, `$` signs are no more javscript code than `xyz`. It is a client side library called Mathjax which allows you to style math formulas in a nice way, just put LaTeX like stuff in paired dollar signs, and the library will try to render it. It appears an empty math expression turned into an empty block which is unfortunate. As an example `$\sqrt{A^3}$` turns into $\sqrt{A^3}$

Comment: Its strange actually. In chrome on desktop, I see a big white space, the space is disproportionately bigger than the number of dollar characters. However, I can see the dollar characters in the Stackexchange android app.

Comment: @falstro sorry, maybe it was the question marks that delimited javascript code? Today we use `<script>`. But dollar signs are still used in it, such as this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607847/how-does-inline-javascript-in-html-work . @Firee Mobile browsers such as safari render html significantly differently than desktop browsers such as chrome. On top of that, many websites serve different page layouts depending on if it detects a mobile or desktop device. Pretty sure all SE pages do that. Usually you can tell when it's something like m.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @DrZ214 this isn't the correct forum, but '$' in javascript is just a letter, alone it's commonly the function name for the jQuery library (but other libraries have adopted the same idea), so when you see `$(...)` it's calling the `$` function with `...` parameters. There never was anything but '<script>' to use script inline in HTML. Maybe you're confusing it with `<?php` which is the start tag for (server side) PHP code? Either way, no injection vulnerability here.

Answer (score 12):

Aviation manufacturers generally design the equipment to comply with legal requirements. Under FAA two hours is what is required by law.

> 14 CFR  121.359–Operating Requirements:  Domestic,  Flag,  and Supplemental  Operations–Cockpit  Voice  Recorders
>
> (i)  By  April  7,  2012, all  turbine  engine-powered  airplanes  subject to  this  section  that are manufactured  before  April  7, 2010, must  have  a  cockpit  voice  recorder  installed that  also—
>
> (1)  Meets  the  requirements  of  §23.1457(d)(6)  or  §25.1457(d)(6)  of  this  chapter, as  applicable;
>
> (2)  **Retains  at  least  the  last  2 hours  of  recorded  information using  a  recorder  that  meets  the standards  of  TSO-C123a,  or  later  revision**;  and
>
> (3)  Is  operated  continuously  from  the  use  of  the  checklist  before  the  flight  to completion of  the final checklist at the  end  of  the  flight.
>
> (4)  If  transport  category,  meets  the  requirements  in §25.1457(a)(3),  (a)(4),  and  (a)(5) of this chapter.
>
> [*The following section has the same requirements for aircraft manufactured after April 7, 2010.*]

The flight data recorder is required to retain 15 hours worth of data.

FAA allows pilots to erase anything on the CVR recorded 30 min (in some cases 15 min) prior. This is probably something that was negotiated between the NTSB and the pilots union to protect the pilots' privacy.  Since it's written into the statute that way I assume modern digital CVR'S must have a function to erase everything but the last 30 min. (@OSUZorba *there's that word again*)

> 14 CFR  121.359 (f)  In  complying  with this  section, an approved  cockpit  voice  recorder  having  an  erasure feature  may  be  used, so that  at  any  time  during  the  operation of  the  recorder, information recorded more than  30  minutes  earlier  may  be erased  or  otherwise obliterated.

This was most likely in response to the 1979 incident that occurred on [TWA flight 841](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TWA_Flight_841_%281979%29?wprov=sfla1) where the pilot was accused of improperly extending flaps during cruise but had erased the CVR when they landed,  so they had no proof. At the time CVR's were still fairly new and pilots balked at having their conversations recorded for privacy reasons, so it was common practice to erase it after each flight. There is still some concern over privacy issues since in some situations the recording can open the pilot up to legal liability.

There are really only a handful of cases where a longer recording would have been useful, most of which involved pilot incapacitation. In 2014 EASA proposed extending the requirement. The European Cockpit Association, which represents pilots released a position paper [.pdf](http://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.eurocockpit.be/sites/default/files/eca_position_easa_opinion_01_2014_on_cvr_uld_14_0626_f.pdf&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjmy9nb2ObMAhVG5yYKHfYCB-g4ChAWCBgwBQ&sig2=pwzgOC_dzBPS1KSxmGOhCQ&usg=AFQjCNGz3Hwm_w1VoqcsQHEarZJpcmm6Sg) stating that they would only support the extension if there were also systems in place to ensure that only the pertinent portions could be used and any other conversation could not be leaked to the public or used in jurisdictions where there are no legal requirements to maintain pilots' privacy.

> ECA  stresses  the  following:
>
> 2. Pilots  submit  to such  recording  under  the  strict  condition  that  the  CVR  data is  to be  used exclusively by  accident  investigation authorities in  the  context  of  their  safety  investigations.  Pilots  are  one of  the few  professions  that  agree  to  being  recorded  at  their  workplace  and  the  consequent  infringement  of their  privacy
> 3. National  and  European  legislators  recognise  the  need  to  protect  CVR  recordings  (Reg.  996/2010). However,  despite  various  legal  provisions  at  EU  and  national  level,  as  well  as  best  practices  in many  airlines,  CVR  data  or  their  transcripts  have  too  often  leaked  to  the  public  and  media , exposing  data  with  private  and  personal  content  –  sometimes  the  last  minutes  of  the  crews’  lives  – to  a  wide  audience,  generating  speculation,  interpretations  and  apportioning  blame  –  in  a  way  that may  be  far  removed  from  what  actually  happened,  what  contributed  to  the accident  and why.
> 4. This  inappropriate  use  and  distribution  of  sensitive  CVR  data  beyond  accident  investigation agencies  negatively  affects  Just  Culture  and  the  safety  improvement  efforts  in  Europe.  Extending CVR duration would increase the  quantity  of  data  available for  misuse  significantly.
> 5. Leaking  of  CVR  data  results  in speculation that  increases  the  pressure on  accident  investigators,  on the  judiciary  to  act  quickly  to  hold  accountable those  ‘responsible’,  and  on  other  authorities  or  public figures  to  come  up  with  quick  answers,  rather  than  waiting  for  the  Final  Report  to  be  published  and generating  mature  safety  improvements.
> 6. Increasing  CVR  duration  would  also  increase  the  data  that  is  potentially  available  to  the  airline management.  While   many  companies  in  Europe  have  internal  procedures  –  and  sometimes agreements  with  the  pilot  representatives  –  in  place  to  ensure  sensitive  data  is  not  misused,  this  is not  the  case  for  all  companies.  Hence,  an  increased  recording  time  –  combined  with  very  powerful digital  storing  facilities  and  the  possibility  to  cross-check  CVR  and  FDM  data  –  would  also  increase the  scope  for  (un)intentional  (ab)use  of  such  data  by  company  management  for  other  than  safety purposes  (e.g.  any  form  of  disciplinary  measures).  Although  this  would  not  be  in  line  with  EU legislation,  not  all  airlines  are  as exemplary  as  some,  and not  all  legislation is adequately  enforced.
> 7. Increasing  CVR  duration  on  European aircraft  also increases  the  risk  of  CVR  data being  used  –  and potentially  made  public  –  by  non-European  authorities,  which  are  not  bound  by  EU  legislation  and the  protections  contained  therein.  This  is  the  case  especially  for  long-haul  operations  (at  which  an increase  of  the  recording  time  is  actually  aimed)  where  the  majority  of  the  flight  is  outside  Europe.  If an  accident  happens  outside  Europe,  the  national  safety  and  judicial  authorities  will  be  entitled  to seize  the  CVR  and  will  be  bound  by  their  own  local  laws,  by  local  political  considerations,  and general  public  pressure.  –  This  would be  an  unintended  –  but  very  real  –  consequence  that  must  be taken  into  account.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the logic behind FAA's 2 hour rule.

Comment: @Firee I'm not sure if there is any specific "logic" behind it. Probably just an arbitrary number that was agreeable to everyone. It's obviously not a technical limitation. You can get a micro SD card that's smaller than a postage stamp and holds 128 GB of memory. That would be many hours worth of voice recording.

Comment: It's a little confusing. The CVR must record up to 2 hours minimum per FAA regulation - but the pilot can at-will delete everything except the last 30 mins? Is that right? Why not just only record 30 mins and have it auto-purge anything older?

Answer (score 7):

> With today's technology in memory storage, where simple voice
>   recorders can record virtually endless durations, why are CVRs limited
>   to only 2 hours. Is it the eternal "cost vs benefit" reason?

This is at least partially the result of the fact that CVR's (and FDR's alike) do not necessarily include the latest and greatest tech out there. [As mentioned in the comments](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/27636/why-are-cockpit-voice-recorders-limited-to-2-hours-recording#comment68365_27636), while they are flying today they were not designed today, last week or even last year. The FAA has some very strict regulations on CVR/FDR from a storage stand point ([you can check out this related question for more info](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/26360/what-data-file-format-is-used-by-fdrs)). It's hard enough to get things approved for use as is, there may be current efforts out there to integrate better storage (and we have seen it slowly) but chances are you will see today's tech in airplanes in 5-10 years, not next week. Of course historically this may have been a data medium limitation and over the years the 2 hours has been found to be sufficient and has become a standard.

> Wouldn't more recording provide greater insight to investigators in
>   case of any disaster?

Generally speaking, no. While there are of course cases that can refute this, the overwhelming amount of aviation accidents happen in a relatively short period of time. If we look back at the history of aviation accidents (for which there is a great deal of data) the chain of events generally occurs over minutes not hours thus recording 2 hours of data prior to an impact is more than enough. If you watch any analysis of an investigation (there are a variety of shows out there on it these days) you will see that more often than not they are analyzing the last minutes of flight data and possibly the conversation that lead up to and occurred during that time.

We have seen a great deal of tech progression in CVR/FDR's over the years. The earliest ones were tape and some even had a primitive system that physically punched data onto a metallic strip. This slowly moved to magnetic tape and now some digital tech has been integrated. It's not that it won't happen it just won't happen overnight.