# Flight Data Monitoring formats

Tags: flight-data-recorder

I would be interested in learning more about Flight Data Monitoring  in order to build data analysis tools.

The most basic question I have, is whether Flight data is recorded using a standard format. If yes, where could I find additional information about this, including sample data

Comment: What flight data, specifically?

Comment: Do those answer your question? [What is the format of data stored by a Flight Data Recorder?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/57375/what-is-the-format-of-data-stored-by-a-flight-data-recorder) and [What data file format is used by FDRs?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/26360/14897)

Comment: @ymb1 Yes indeed those questions have answers to mine. My question is a duplicate

Comment: @GdD the obvious data such as latitude, longitude, altitude. This can be easily obtained from websites. But also the less obvious: engine thrust, fuel burn.